# What is the relation between an algorithm and its implementation at the level of code?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, turing-machines, programming-languages, semantics

Is there any isomorphism or equivalence relation? What strictly bind these two together?

Answer (score 2):

An algorithm is a method for performing some task; an implementation is an expression of that method in a particular language.

Comment: Thank you for the response. "Expression" is a vague word. Is there a rigorous mathematical relationship between algorithm and it's implementation in a programming language?

Comment: @AhmedAbdullah You can make one, but which one would depend on the level of granularity you're okay with. You would likely add require something from the implementations' output, but may or may not want a require something about the running time, or perhaps some mapping of certain lines in the algorithm to certain parts of the implementation.